# Grails dynamic baseurl for multi-url webapp

Tags: url, grails, vhosts

Any one have an idea how to use a dynamic baseurl??

f.e: I have file.war and I want to deploy the same war for www.webapp1.com & www.webapp2.com

I tried to use alias for my server.xml host, and I tried to use a separated host in server.xml.. but every time I try webapp2.com url I get the webapp1.com.

Comment: Can't you just copy `file.war` into `file1.war` and `file2.war`, configuring your server to deal with both?

Comment: @luck84: Nope, can't do that because grails force the redirection..

Answer (score 3):

Grails registers a bean named `grailsLinkGenerator`.  I believe you can accomplish what you're trying to do by overriding this bean with your own custom logic.  Your bean must implement the [LinkGenerator](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/LinkGenerator.java) interface. You might find it easiest to extend [DefaultLinkGenerator](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/DefaultLinkGenerator.groovy) or [CachingLinkGenerator](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/CachingLinkGenerator.java)